# Am I understanding this probability question correctly?

Tags: probability

> $X$ is a geometric r.v. with $p = 0.9$. Find $Pr(3<X<10)$ and $\Pr(X=7|3<X<10)$.

First off, geometric r.v. with p = 0.9 has a PDF of:
$$P_X(x) = 0.9(1-0.9)^{x-1}\;\;\;\text{for} \;x>0 \\
\Pr(3<X<10) = \sum_{x=4}^{9}0.9(0.1)^{x-1}$$
and
$$Pr(X=7|3<X<10) = \frac{Pr(X=7)}{Pr(3<X<10)}$$
Am I understanding this probability question correct?

One more quick question regarding independence: conditioned on ${3<X<10}$, are $\left\{{X=4}\right\}$ and $\left\{{X=5}\right\}^c$ independent? Is my attempt correct?
$$P[AB] = P[A]P[B] \implies \text{independence} \\
\text{if} \; \frac{Pr(X=4)}{Pr(3<X<10)} \cdot \frac{Pr(X \neq 5)}{Pr(3<X<10)}=\frac{Pr(X \neq 5)}{Pr(3<X<10)} \; \implies \text{independence} $$
Therefore my answer is "Not independent".

Comment: Also you might find it useful that $\mathsf P(X\geq x) = (1-0.9)^{x-1}$

Comment: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/306553 mathjax references.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are doing great.

You might like to use the formula of [geometric sum](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GeometricSeries.html) to evaluate $P(3< X< 10)$.

$$\sum_{k=0}^{n}r^k = \frac{1-r^{n+1}}{1-r}$$

Alternatively, use $Pr(X \leq 9) - Pr(X \leq 3)$.

Comment: What is the formula of geometric sum?

Comment: Included in the post. Useful if you need to add multiple terms that are in geometric progression. You can also check out the CDF of geometric distribution and ue it to evaluate that term.

Comment: Another portion of the problem states that X is the number of transmissions for a packet success.
How would I approach finding E[number of transmissions for success]?

Comment: Use the expected value of geometric distribution.

Comment: E[X] for geometric distribution is $\frac{1}{p}=\frac{1}{0.9}=1.11$. What do I do after?

Comment: huh, i thought that is why what the question is asking?

Comment: Is that all that there is to it?

Comment: yup. that's all.

Comment: Ok thanks! One more quick question about independence. Could you check my work? I've updated the OP with the question.

Comment: try to stick to a question per post and also use better title. Your working is not correct. Think of what is the intersection.

Comment: I've posted a new question and redid the work. Thanks for all your help thus far, I really appreciate it!